# Remove series indicator/plot legend AndroidPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

I realise AndroidPlot has a forum but it isn't the most active so i'll chance my arm here...

I'm trying to remove the series indicator or plot legend from my XY plot using the AndroidPlot library. I don't want to remove the series from the plot itself, just the legend.

I've seen it done on AndroidPlot examples but with the limited documentation it's difficult to find methods to do the stuff like remove the legen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK I have the following code to do this.  This is not tested on the very latest version but hopefully is still good.

```
    if (!mKeyOn)
        mDynamicPlot.getLayoutManager()
                .remove(mDynamicPlot.getLegendWidget());
    if (!mDomainLabelOn)
        mDynamicPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(
                mDynamicPlot.getDomainLabelWidget());
```

Looks like the trick is to get the layoutManager.

Comment: Ye I've triend multitoucPlot.setLegendWidget(null);

Comment: Ye I've have tried Plot.setLegendWidget(null); It doesn't get rid of the legend icon... driving me a bit insane at this stage

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Androidplot's [XML Styling with Configurator](http://androidplot.com/docs/xml-styling-with-configurator/#Usage) and thanks to reflection remove plot legend by simply specifying it's visibility in XML layout file like this:

```
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
...
    androidPlot.legendWidget.visible="false"
... />
```

If there is no need to change your legend dynamically, I think it's better to place such a styling in the XML file.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the code, [setLegendWidget](https://androidplot.jira.com/source/browse/~br=trunk/ANDROIDPLOT/trunk/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/xy/XYPlot.java?r1=146&r2=146&u=3#to832) only updates the local handle for the LegendWidget but does not update the LayoutManager, which is what is actually invoked when it comes time to do the drawing.  If you implement Ifor's (upvoted) suggestion you should have success since it interacts with the LayoutManager directly:

```
plot.getLayoutManager().remove(plot.getDomainLabelWidget());
```

Another option is to hide the Legend like this:

```
plot.getLegendWidget().setVisible(false);
```

Provided (in light of the info above) that you are not also trying to substitute/remove the legend widget with a previous call to setLegendWidget().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove **only one** (or a specific) series legend from the legend widget simply use:

```
yourSeriesFormater.setLegendIconEnabled(false);
```

This worked for me.