# Remove a lengend from an XYPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

Am using AndroidPlot on my project and it's just great so far. This is what i got.

[image: plot with androidplot showing 4 series and a legend]

Now am trying to remove one of the series indicators from the legend. Actually i want to keep only the first one (the blue one) cause the others are self explanatory.

Am not asking how to remove the legend it self (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413758/665823 for that issue).

If someone can help me i'll be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not at all sure you can do that.  best bet is to look at the source for the ledged widget.  You may be able to extend it to tweak the functionality.

Comment: @lfor I manage to do this without having to tweek the source code. See my answer if your interested. Thanks for the advice anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a tweek that allows me to do what i need. To achieve this the series that i need to be shown must be added to the plot first over the ones i need to hide :

```
// I add the blue serie first
LineAndPointFormatter mFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter();
mFormat.configure(context, R.xml.plot_blue);
graphView.addSeries(serieMesures, mFormat);

// I add the other colors after
for (XYSeries serie : seriesSeuils) {
     LineAndPointFormatter sFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter();
     if (serie.getTitle().equals("RED") {
        sFormat.configure(context, R.xml.plot_red);
     } 
     else if (serie.getTitle().equals("ORANGE")) {
        sFormat.configure(context, R.xml.plot_orange);
     }
     else if (serie.getTitle().equals("YELLOW")) {
        sFormat.configure(context, R.xml.plot_yellow);
     }
     graphView.addSeries(serie, sFormat);
}
```

Then i just created a legend where there is only enough space to show the series i need (in my case just the first one).

```
// This is what does the trick! A Table with 1 line and 1 column 
// so the other series can't be rendered in the LegendWidget
graphView.getLegendWidget().setTableModel(new DynamicTableModel(1, 1));

// Other customizations (size and position)
graphView.getLegendWidget().setSize(new SizeMetrics(55, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE, legendWith, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE));
graphView.getLegendWidget().setPositionMetrics(
     new PositionMetrics(20,
                         XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT,
                         20,
                         YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP,
                         AnchorPosition.RIGHT_TOP));
graphView.getLegendWidget().setBackgroundPaint(bgPaint);
graphView.getLegendWidget().setTextPaint(txPaint);
graphView.getLegendWidget().setBorderPaint(brPaint);
graphView.getLegendWidget().setPadding(10, 1, 10, 1);
```

And voila!

[image: androidplot showing 4 series and just one in the legendwidget]